# Регулярное выражение для имени фамилии и даты

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

У меня есть строка с именем фамилией и датой. Они могут иметь 4 вида:

1. Виктор Потрышкин 1998 год.
2. 1998 год - Виктор Патрышкин
3. Виктор Потрышкин 1998 года.
4. 1998 года - Виктор Патрышкин.

Как мне сосатвить одно регулярное выражение, что бы получить Фамилию, Имя и Дату без слова "год(а)"?

Comment: @Visman, исправил

Comment: Какой диалект регулярных выражений вам нужен?

Comment: @mymedia, в смысле какой диалект?

Comment: Существует несколько различных [синтаксисов регулярных выражений](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F#.D0.A0.D0.B0.D0.B7.D0.BD.D0.BE.D0.B2.D0.B8.D0.B4.D0.BD.D0.BE.D1.81.D1.82.D0.B8_.D1.80.D0.B5.D0.B3.D1.83.D0.BB.D1.8F.D1.80.D0.BD.D1.8B.D1.85_.D0.B2.D1.8B.D1.80.D0.B0.D0.B6.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B9). На каком языке вы пишите?

Comment: @mymedia, php :)

Comment: @mymedia, добавил в теги

Comment: О, значит мой ответ подходит :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот таким можно:

```
(.+) (.+) (\d{4}) года?\.?|(\d{4}) года? - (.+) (.+)
```

Живой пример: https://regex101.com/r/5eZrNR/3

Comment: спасибо большое

Answer (score 1):

Вариант с возвратом данных в одних и тех же группа вне зависимости где написан год:

```
/(?=.*?(\p{L}+)\s+(\p{L}+)).*?(\d+)\s+год/u
```

Тест https://regex101.com/r/OeJOIQ/1

P.S. Для кодировки UTF-8 и для имен и фамилий состоящих из букв :) При наличии тире в имени/фамилии, данная регулярка работает с ошибками!